# Github push error: this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size

Tags: github

I want to push an update for my repo, but getting this error:

```
remote: warning: File assets/img/slider/mockups/1/slider-mobile1.1.psd is 50.59 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: cea347c87f654e4a71816908a45d11e6f66dd3d32631cb6cd86532f316581c28
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File assets/img/slider/mockups/1/slider1.1.psd is 109.18 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/yusufcode/dji-destek.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/yusufcode/dji-destek.git'
```

I tried [Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/):

```
$git lfs install
```

--

```
$git lfs track "*.psd"
```

But the problem doesn't solve...

Comment: github has 100MB repo limit try gitlab or gerrit they have 10GB limit

Comment: `git lfs track` is not sufficient: you must run that command *before* adding and committing the file. You already added and committed the file, so this is too late. See `git lfs migrate` instead.